# Создать запись клиента на свободное время MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Как реализовать составление расписание тренера и запись клиента к этому тренеру на определённое время, учитывая, что 2 клиента не могут записаться на одно и тоже время. Чтобы в выпадающем списке отображалось только оставшееся свободное время, с учётом записанных ранее клиентов ( по аналогии с записью к врачу в поликлинике ).
Есть модель клиента:

```
[Table("Clients")]
public class Client : Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("ФИО")]
    public string ClientFIO { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Имя")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Фамилия")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Отчество")]
     public string ThirdName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Дата рождения")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Пол")]
    public string Sex { get; set; }
```

Аналогичным образом будет выглядеть тренер.
Только начинаю изучать MVC и хотелось получить рекомендации по созданию самого примитивного, но рабочего решения.

Comment: Так а в чем проблема то?

Comment: @tym32167 не имею представления как и какими методами это реализовывать

Comment: ну то есть вам нужна таблица с записями клиентов на тренировку, и перед добавлением новой записи, вам надо убедиться, что в таблице на указанное время для указанного тренера никто ещё не записан. Всё, вперед.